# max count with joins

Tags: sql, select, join, max

I have 3 tables:

**users:**

```
Id   Login
1    John
2    Bill
3    Jim
```

**computers:**

```
Id   Name
1    Computer1
2    Computer2
3    Computer3
4    Computer4
5    Computer5
```

**sessions:**

```
UserId   ComputerId   Minutes
1        2            47
2        1            32
1        4            15
2        5            5
1        2            7
1        1            40
2        5            31
```

I would like to display this resulting table:

```
Login   Total_sess   Total_min   Most_freq_computer   Sess_on_most_freq   Min_on_most_freq
John    4            109         Computer2            2                   54
Bill    3            68          Computer5            2                   36
Jim     -            -           -                    -                   -
```

Myself I can only cover first 3 columns with:

```
SELECT Login, COUNT(sessions.UserId), SUM(Minutes) FROM users
LEFT JOIN sessions
ON users.Id = sessions.UserId GROUP BY users.Id
```

And some kind of other columns with:

```
SELECT main.*
FROM (SELECT UserId, ComputerId, COUNT(*) AS cnt ,SUM(Minutes)
FROM sessions
GROUP BY UserId, ComputerId) AS main
INNER JOIN (
SELECT ComputerId, MAX(cnt) AS maxCnt FROM (
SELECT ComputerId, UserId, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM sessions GROUP BY ComputerId, UserId
)
AS Counts GROUP BY ComputerId) 
                    AS maxes
ON main.ComputerId = maxes.ComputerId
AND main.cnt = maxes.maxCnt
```

But I need to get whole resulting table in one query. I feel I'm doing something completely wrong. Need help.

Comment: It looks like one query - do you mean that you don't want to use nested queries? Also, which SQL are you using? PostreSQL? MySQL? MS SQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you are:

```
SELECT    u.login, t1.total_sess, t1.total_min, t2.mf, t2.sess_mf, t2.min_mf
FROM      users u
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT   userid, COUNT(minutes) AS total_sess, SUM(minutes) AS total_min
  FROM     sessions
  GROUP BY userid
) AS t1 ON t1.userid = u.id
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT   userid, name AS mf, COUNT(*) AS sess_mf, SUM(minutes) AS min_mf
  FROM     sessions s
  JOIN     computers c ON c.id = s.computerid
  GROUP BY userid, computerid
  HAVING   COUNT(computerid) >= ALL(SELECT   COUNT(*)
                                    FROM     sessions s2
                                    WHERE    s2.userid = s.userid
                                    GROUP BY s2.computerid)
) AS t2 ON t2.userid = u.id
```

I'm using MySQL syntax, but it should be pretty portable.

If you need anything more, feel free to ask!

**EDIT:** I updated the query, the previous one was wrong :(

Comment: @Yassin: There's still a problem with your `HAVING` clause. At the moment it works because both users had a `Sess_on_most_freq` of 2, but if you add another session for Bill on Computer 5, the query would break. Adding `WHERE user_id = s.user_id` in the HAVING clause should fix it.

Comment: Thanks! You are awesome! I would appreciate if you recommend me some goob books on SQL.

Comment: @Daniel, good catch, also in that case GROUP BY userid is redundant.

Comment: @trixet: Learning SQL (ISBN 0596007272) and SQL In A Nutshell, 2nd Edition (ISBN 0596004818)